# Find salt in the blowfish encrypted hash

Tags: c++, blowfish, crypt

This is kind of very basic question. I have searched for help regarding this but couldn't find any concrete answer to it. Therefore i am asking it specifically here.

The use case is, i want to find the weak password referring to the list of hashes available. For that i am have to compare the hash of each known/common words with the available hash. All this is done in C++ for Unix using openssl/blowfish.h

However, to create the hash of this guess word needs to be generated using the same salt that was used for the password hashes.

My question here is how can i extract the salt from password hashes. 
Suppose, following is my hash:

$2a$10$FTx8T5QrEbxYVe.NJ6iOhuei.V9qgl60xF8/8s7iZRDIlOl.ibDEW

What is salt in this? or how i can achieve the goal? Any pointer would be great!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683350/blowfish-salt-length-for-the-crypt-function

Comment: Nice article by Jeff Atwood about salt and hashing and rainbow-tables http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.htmlto

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the password hash as the salt -- it is smart enough to extract itself. This is the convention of `crypt()`

See [How Passwords Work in Unix, Mac OS, and Windows](http://www.cromwell-intl.com/security/password.html) under *Modern Unix and "BSD-style" hashing*.

Note: the `salt` parameter of `crypt()` is NOT the salt.  It is `$algorithm$salt$MORESALTsomething`, so you should never extract the salt yourself.  -- it is called `salt` for historical (DES-era) reason.

See also [Why does crypt/blowfish generate the same hash with two different salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225720/why-does-crypt-blowfish-generate-the-same-hash-with-two-different-salts)

Comment: Yes. I have seen the second link. based on that only, i had made some assumptions which are actually not working for me or giving unexpected results. I am unable to make out how i should be using blowfish APIs for my use case.

Comment: can i achieve the same using blowfish API?

Comment: I don't think so -- the blowfish used in password hash is a modified one.

Answer (score 1):

The "salt" of a password hash function is concatenated with the password, and the resulting string is then hashed. To get back the salt, that would mean you'd need to get back the string which was hashed. Obviously, that has two major issues:

1. If you'd be able to get back that hashed string, it would also contain the plaintext password. That would be a major security failing of the hash function.
2. You'd also have to figure out which part of the concatenated string is the salt, and which the password.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the point of the salt? That you don't know what it is? So nobody can come and do what you're trying to do now?

The way I understand salt is this:

- You have a string, let's call it `password`.
- And you have and algorithm that takes a string and produces a hash from it. Let's call it `blowfish`

  - is that even correct? is blowfish a hashing algorithm? I don't think so!!!.
  - Let's call our algorithm `md5`.
- `md5` will produce a hash for `password`, but it will always produce the same one
- You have a bad guy. Let's call him `Mrun`.
- `Mrun` tries to find out the `password` by testing `md5` with a bunch of known passwords from a dictionary
- by not using just `password`, but instead `password + salt`, a different hash is produced and `Mrun` is foiled.

If you need to find the salt, you will have to have at least one known combination of password and hash. Then you can try to use brute force to figure out the salt. Good luck. Oh, and I hope you're not being evil here. Oh, and I hope the rest of the evil beings are also clueless...

Comment: You have got some misconception here --- If you can't get the salt, how can you verify if the password is correct?   The salt is for prevent *precompiled tables*, but not on the spot tables. This is also why you should not reuse salt.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - if you find the salt (by guessing, applying hashing algorithm to password and guess and checking with known hash) then you can recompile your table using the salt and crack the rest of the passwords.

Comment: I agree with J-16. Each user will have its own salt value, in a proper setup. There's no such thing as _the_ salt. I.e. the password table will have three columns: `User, Salt, Hash`.